How to setup a table domain for an asset spec in Maximo Asset Management 7613?
I'm trying to setup a table domain to use with an asset spec for the first time. So far, I get an empty list when I click on the lookup icon in the alnvalue column. Can anyone help?
Here's what I did:

Created a new table domain. I left the Validation and List where clause empty for testing so I could get avalue in the lookup list.

Created the new attribute in CLASSSPEC
enter image description here

Modified LOOKUP.XML to add the new lookup. (see below)


</table>
        <table id="GLCOMPONENTS" inputmode="readonly" selectmode="single">
        <tablebody displayrowsperpage="20" filterable="true" filterexpanded="true" id="GLCOMPONENTS_tablebody">
            <tablecol dataattribute="compvalue" id="GLCOMPONENTS_tablebody_col_1" mxevent="selectrecord" mxevent_desc="Aller à %1" sortable="true" type="link"/>
            <tablecol dataattribute="comptext" id="GLCOMPONENTS_tablebody_col_2" mxevent="selectrecord" mxevent_desc="Aller à %1" sortable="true" type="link"/>
        </tablebody>
    </table>

